# JQuery on document ready after load second document

Tags: jquery, load, document, ready

I have web page in which one part is changed dynamically (clock on menu item).
I use JQuery in both pages - main - and dynamic and use function on document ready.
I cannot use use only in main webpage -because some elements appear only after load internal page.
So question is:
 Will be function onDocumentReady executed only in internal page or in both?
Thanks.

Comment: How is the "internal page" loaded? Are you pulling it in on the server? AJAX? Iframe?

Comment: I'm sort of hazy as to what you're asking, but a given document's onDocumentReady function will call once that document hits the event that is attached to the document ready stage. IF the master page hangs until its child page is loaded then yes, the master page's document ready event will fire once they've both loaded. If it does not hang, then relying on the master's document ready will not be sufficient. What is it that you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Yes, using AJAX. <div id="mydiv"></div>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using an AJAX call to load your new content, then you'll have to use [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate) to set up your event bindings or set things up manually in the AJAX success callback; if you need to do something that is more complicated than binding a simple click handler (such as binding a jQuery-UI button or a form validator), then you'll have to do it by hand. For example, if you're using the [`load` convenience function](http://api.jquery.com/load) to pull in new content:

```
$('#mydiv').load('/where/it/comes/from', function(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
    // Bind events and widgets to the new things inside #mydiv
});
```